# What happens to additional requests when HaProxy hits its max session limit

Tags: performance, high-availability, haproxy

I have HA proxy load balancing across 3 web servers. The session limit is set to 200 and I am seeing the "Curr sessions" hit the limit. Am I losing traffic or are the additional requests queued up and served later?

I know this is not ideal, I am going to bump it up but I am curious to know what is actually happening.

My application behind the load balancer does not depend on sticky sessions.

Comment: Are you talking about the `rate-limit` session rate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Documentation at [1wt.eu](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) for version 1.3 it will queue the additional requests.

But only if there are less than `maxqueue` requests in the queue already, for `timeout queue` seconds, if after that timeout no unsaturated server is found, the request will be dropped.

More Info see here: [HAProxy Doc](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.3/doc/haproxy-en.txt) and here: [Sample Config](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.3/examples/antidos.cfg), as well as here: [Article about queuing in HAProxy](http://web.archive.org/web/20130503183842/http://technology.posterous.com/scaling-tip-tailor-your-haproxy-queues-to-the)